# Best way to add responsive attributes to Slick Slider using data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am trying to figure out how I can make one of my slick slider enabled elements responsive using data attributes only.

This is what my slick enabled element currently looks like:

```
<div class="slider" 
    data-slides-to-show="3" 
    data-css-ease="linear" 
    data-center-mode="true" 
    data-arrows="true" 
    data-show-dots="false"
    data-pause-on-hover="false"
    data-autoplay="false"
    data-draggable="false" 
    data-fade="false" 
    data-infinite="false">
</div>
```

And I initialize my slider like this:

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    $(this).slick($(this).data());
});
```

Is there a way I can add an additional data attribute to my html element so that at a certain breakpoint, it will only show 1 slide instead of 3?